# How to make JSON array string to newline string in js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, string, stringify

In React I'm trying to render the JSON data I'm getting from the server to readable data.

Here is the string from the server

```
"[{\"mat_type\":1,\"mat_title\":\"Title1\",\"mat_unit\":2,\"mat_price\":44000,\"mat_cost\":2000},{\"mat_type\":2,\"mat_title\":\"Title2\",\"mat_unit\":2,\"mat_price\":44000,\"mat_cost\":2000},{\"mat_id\":1,\"mat_title\":\"Title\",\"mat_unit\":2,\"mat_price\":4400,\"mat_cost\":2000,\"mat_status\":0}]"
```

I want to make it readable data with newline and spacing on it.

Here is my quick function

```
<Typography>
  {{JSON.parse(item.api_text).map((item) => {
    console.log(item);
    return `<br>${JSON.stringify(item, null, '\t')}</br>`;
  })} }
</Typography>
```

Here item.api_text is the string above.
I know this will create error but I want something like this. Thanks

Edit:
I want to display it like this on document not in console.

```
[{
    "mat_type": 1,
    "mat_title": "Title1",
    "mat_unit": 2,
    "mat_price": 44000,
    "mat_cost": 2000
},
{
    "mat_type": 2,
    "mat_title": "Title2",
    "mat_unit": 2,
    .....
```

Comment: ok thanks, what about new line after every key-value pair

Comment: `'\t'` might be in the wrong place. Try using `JSON.stringify(item, '\t', 2)`

Comment: Can you show an example of what you want, pls?

Comment: To preserve line breaks and white space, wrap the json string output with a `<pre>` element

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var json="[{\"mat_type\":1,\"mat_title\":\"Title1\",\"mat_unit\":2,\"mat_price\":44000,\"mat_cost\":2000},{\"mat_type\":2,\"mat_title\":\"Title2\",\"mat_unit\":2,\"mat_price\":44000,\"mat_cost\":2000},{\"mat_id\":1,\"mat_title\":\"Title\",\"mat_unit\":2,\"mat_price\":4400,\"mat_cost\":2000,\"mat_status\":0}]";

<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function () 
  {

var jo=JSON.parse(json);

json=JSON.stringify(jo,null,4);

 $("#json").html(json);

 });

</script>
```

create html

```
 <Typography id="json" style= "white-space: pre-wrap;">
</Typography>
```

output

```
[
    {
        "mat_type": 1,
        "mat_title": "Title1",
        "mat_unit": 2,
        "mat_price": 44000,
        "mat_cost": 2000
    },
    {
        "mat_type": 2,
        "mat_title": "Title2",
        "mat_unit": 2,
        "mat_price": 44000,
        "mat_cost": 2000
    },
    {
        "mat_id": 1,
        "mat_title": "Title",
        "mat_unit": 2,
        "mat_price": 4400,
        "mat_cost": 2000,
        "mat_status": 0
    }
]
```

Comment: Ok. But I want it in the document, not in the console. Thanks

Comment: @xxxhomie21 You are welcome. Why it is in a console ?  I can't see any console in my code.  variable  json is a string and that is it.   It is not a free coders resource where everybody should create a full code for you. I posted a hint  Your task is to put this string where to you want  and tell everybody  is it usefull or not .

Comment: @xxxhomie21 I updated my answer. Try it in your browser now.

Comment: Thanks, that worked but in react we have to write style as style={{whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap'}} to get work. Have u used jquery in ur function?

Comment: @xxxhomie21 $("#json").html(json); is jquery but i can be easily replaced by javascript

Answer (score 1):

guys thanks to @evolutionxbox i've found a way to do this in react.

here inside my react component. pre works very well in preserving the next line.

```
            <pre>
              {JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(item.api_text), null, 3)}
            </pre>
```

Another alternative, style can be given to the tags known as white-space: 'pre-wrap', Thanks to @Serge. I've used </code/> to make it look better

```
          <Typography id='json' style={{whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap'}}>
            <code>
              {JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(item.api_text), null, 3)}
            </code>
          </Typography>
```